# OSPF, do the end device networks need to be advertised when setting it up?

Tags: networking, routing, cisco, ospf

Giving this topology as an example,
[image: Network topology]

I am working on an exercise for university and up so far I have implemented inter vlan routing, spanning tree, link aggregation and DHCP. For the last part I need to implement OSPF and my question is:

Once setting up the OSPF in each router, do I need to advertise the network that corresponds to the IP's given to each end device or should I only advertise the networks corresponding to each of the router's links?

At the moment I have configured OSPF in all 4 routers with the network corresponding to each of the links and can ping between all routers but not from end device to ELSEWHERE/EDGE or Campus.

Hope I was clear enough about my question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `redistribute connected`

Comment: `show ip route ospf`

Comment: and yes,  if you have l3 interfaces on your switches,  set therm up the same

Comment: @JacobEvans I have just done it and worked perfectly. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: cool,  now do the same with ipv6:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configure ospf on any device routing L3 traffic (switches included)

then the easiest thing is to just `redistribute connected`

use `show ip route ospf` to confirm.